# MySQL GTID error 1236

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, gtid

I am try to reduce machine come to live in production.. MySQL is making bottleneck. What i trying. I update code in one machine and also MySQL restore everything is working fine after this i am making EC2 AMI and launched machine from autoscaling group. now in this instance i am not taking and any live dump. after start MySQL and make it replication but its showing me GTID error. these all processes taking 30 to 40 minutes.

> Last_IO_Error: Got fatal error 1236 from master when
>   reading data from binary log: 'The slave is connecting using CHANGE
>   MASTER TO MASTER_AUTO_POSITION = 1, but the master has purged binary
>   logs containing GTIDs that the slave requires.

any body can tell what i doing wrong. but if i take fresh dump and restore this in live machine its working. MySQL version 5.6.17.

Comment: Please correct the question grammatically. The question is not clear in itself. I advise you to check the MySQL documentation on how to configure GTID based replication

Answer (score 0):

You need to take dump from Master to replicate.

> master has purged binary logs containing GTIDs that the slave
>   requires.

Master delete its binary logs and create a new binary logs file. That's the reason when you implementing replication after taking dump is working because it's getting `gtid_executed` and `gtid_purged` that is available in the current binary log.

But when you are implementing without dump, The `gtid_executed` and `gtid_purged` getting matched because Mater already purged it.

So you must have to take dump and even sometimes you need to set the `gtid_purged` manually on slave.

You can read this, it has explained very well.
https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/02/08/how-to-createrestore-a-slave-using-gtid-replication-in-mysql-5-6/

Comment: the answer should rather cover more detail as to what needs to be checked first if the user sees this error, second whether missing gtids are really missing or this error is false. Also what this error really means and various causes of this error.